# Only add item to array if unique otherwise delete - React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

My function keeps pushing duplicates and i don't know why.

Is it possible to update my code so that `state` contains only dates that are clicked once and removed when clicked twice?

So kind of being able to toggle dates in state.

(Because if misclicked, the user should be able te remove the selected date)

```
const [dates, setDates] = useState([])

const handleDayClick = (day) => {
    let newArray = [...dates];
    let indexItem = newArray.indexOf(day);
    indexItem === -1 ? newArray.push(day) : newArray.splice(day, 1);
    setDates(newArray)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(dates);
  }, [dates]);

  return (
     <DayPicker selectedDays={dates} onDayClick={handleDayClick} />
  )
```

The `day` parameter in `handleDayClick` returns values as strings like:

```
Fri Mar 05 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

I know there are related questions on Stackoverflow about this but i've been trying all of them the past hour and i can't find a fix.

If someone could look into it, that would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should remove an item using it's index `newArray.splice(indexItem, 1);`

Comment: @Yousaf `.indexOf()` doesn't use a callback, just the value. The `.findIndex()` method does.

Comment: @OriDrori oh right. My bad!

Comment: @OriDrori it is still pushing duplicates ... only after an item is added for the second time, then it gets deleted

Comment: Something to do with react state?

Answer (score 1):

I worked on something similar with multiple arrays for my filter state and this was the solution I came up with.

```
    const clickHandler = (array, value, setter) => {
        if (array.includes(value)) {
            const newArray = array.filter(e => e !== value)
            setter(newArray)
        } else {
            const newArray = [...array, value]
            setter(newArray)
        }
    }
```

Where array is the state, value is the new date you might want to add or remove & the setter is the setState function of that state.

Comment: Hey Nobert, I would like to use your solution but can you help me explain how I would send the `array, value and setter` parameters with the `clickhandler function`?

Comment: The array is simply the initial state of your component (in your case, dates), the value is the new date you want to add (day), and the setter is the setState function (setDates), I made mine like this so it could work with 2 or more state arrays.